# Serial - Send data to Arduino while Arduino sending data

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, code-review

Arduino send data to PC each iteration. When I'm trying to send data to Arduino while receiving data from it, it takes too long. `Serial.available()` returns false even I sent data from PC. But if I add delay like 20-30 ms, problem fixed. Can't I use serial simultaneously?

PS: It's Arduino mega and I'm using http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/ library for serial communication.

Example code:

```cpp
void loop(){

  if(Serial.available())
    Serial.write("goodbye", 7);
    Serial.write("hello", 5);
  }
```

In this situation, it takes long time to write "goodbye" after I sent data to Arduino.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code. Format the code using the code formatting markdown (four leading spaces). For help see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You should be able to do this by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K` to have your browser do this for you.

Comment: @Nick Gammon, done.

Comment: That's not **all** your code is it? What baud rate are you using? In any case, since you are sending "hello" every time around `loop` the output buffer will be filled with `hello` before you get a chance to insert `goodbye`. Your "delay" solution probably gives the output buffer time to empty.

Comment: @Nick Gammon 9600.

Comment: And I lid a led when receive message. I forget to write it. I`ll add full code when I`m open PC. I dont have full code by now.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on what Nick Gammon says, don't try to use the serial output to debug serial.  Perhaps try using the built-in LED instead; you can use an oscilloscope to find out how much time it is spending reading characters.

The following is how I've been reading a line at a time using non-blocking operations:

```
const int SERIAL_BUFFER_LENGTH = 100;

// The +1 assures we'll always have room for null termination
char g_serial_buffer[SERIAL_BUFFER_LENGTH+1];
int g_char_count;         // index into serial buffer

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // or 115200 if your host supports it
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  g_char_count = 0;
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available() > 0) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    char c = Serial.read();   // won't block because Serial.available() > 0
    if (c == '\n') {
      g_serial_buffer[g_char_count] = '\0';  // null terminate
      process_buffer(g_serial_buffer);
      g_char_count = 0;
    } else if (g_char_count < SERIAL_BUFFER_LENGTH) {
      g_serial_buffer[g_char_count++] = c;
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  Serial.print(".");
}

// process_buffer: do whatever it is you intended to do with a 
// line of received text...
void process_buffer(char *buffer) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if(Serial.available())
    while(Serial.read());
    Serial.write("goodbye", 7);
    Serial.write("hello", 5);
  }
```

I think you have to read what you get in the serial port.